# Problem with special characters in .toc files

Tags: table-of-contents, auxiliary-files, input-encodings

I have an odd problem with special characters (in this case the Swedish `åäö`), that pops up in my `.toc` file. If I remove the `.toc` file everything works OK except I get an empty table of contents. When I re-run `pdflatex`, I get errors on every line in the `.toc` file that has either of `åäö` in it (which, as it happens, is every line...).

I've tried to produce a MWE example of this, but I'm unable to reproduce the problem with other files. However, I've noticed that for other files, `åäö` in the `.toc` file are replaced as follows:

```
å -> \IeC {\r a}
ä -> \IeC {\"a}
ö -> \IeC {\"o}
```

In the `.toc` file for the failing document, only `å` is replaced. Why could this be? What can I do about it?

**Clarification:** As I said, I have tried but been unable to reproduce this error in a MWE. (The full version is a pretty advanced structure with templates, frame and content files compiled by a python script calling pdflatex via `os.system()`, so I can't really just "scale off" one piece after another...) However, I *can* give the following information:

- All files are saved in utf-8.
- I'm using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[swedish]{babel}`.
- The python file starts with `#coding: utf8`

Comment: Perhaps post a minimal code example that produces this problem. Until now, we don't know the encoding you're using neither we know if you're using babel or not.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @Caramdir: I get lots of variations of `! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:Â„ not set up for use with LaTeX.` in the log file, along with things like `Missing character: There is no Â in font cmcsc10!`.

Comment: In addititon, there are problems with rendering these letters in some headings, particularly within `\textsc{}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the non-ascii-chars like ä or ö get in the toc, this means that they are not active. Perhaps you are storing some of your titles in commands before inputenc has been loaded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\test{ÅÄÖ}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{\test}

\end{document}
```

My example doesn't give an error, but its possible that your python code insert an utf8 char tex can't handle.

Comment: This is very likely the cause - I'll do some testing and get back...

Comment: Thanks! I had to rewrite quite a lot of my code to handle this, but when I include `inputenc` *before* setting up all the titles etc, everything works as expected =)

Answer (score 1):

From the [`inputenc`](http://tug.org/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/inputenc.pdf) documentation:

> 1.3.3 Unicode char <*charcode*> is not set up for use with LaTeX
>
> This is the dreaded error message that one will receive if the document contains an
>   UTF-8 character that isn't known to LATEX. It is quite possible that the character
>   looks very unsuspicious and is rendered perfectly in the editor.
>
> ...
>
> However, even if LATEX can type that character in question it may not
>   have been set up in which case you would need to do that yourself via
>   `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`.

So, something like `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E4}{\"a}` might work. You'd probably need to see which Unicode glyph is the one you're trying to use (this example straight from the manual, section 1.2).

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK. I'm unable to find what numbers and glyphs I should use for the other five characters. Any clues?

Comment: See this: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ . Does it work otherwise?

Comment: I added `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E4}{\"a}` as well as one command for each of the other (ÅÄÖåö) troubling characters, but with no positive results - I still have warnings in my log file about undefined characters (\u8:Å, among others) and I still get an exit code that suggests failure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a meaningful encoding such as

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

but also take care that your editor uses the same encoding and that the file itself has this encoding too. For instance, one may download a `latin1` encoded file but edit it with `utf8` option and the other way round.