# Input unicode/diacritics into package options

Tags: unicode

I would like to define a new set of labels for my pictures like this:

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={Seznam grafů}]{Graf}
```

However, latex refuses to recognize "ů" in the package option and throws an error on me:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
```

Minimal working example is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={Seznam grafů}]{Graf}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents


\listoffigures
\listofGrafs
\end{document}
```

The first compilation works, but then it fails on second compilation, as the generated `.toc` file is causing trouble (so this is similar to [Problem with special characters in .toc files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4807/problem-with-special-characters-in-toc-files) but the accepted solution there does not help as I specify `inputenc` early enough). The generated `.toc` file goes like this:

```
\select@language {czech}
\contentsline {section}{Seznam obr\'azk\r {u}}{1}
\contentsline {section}{Seznam graf·}{1}
```

If I replace `·` with `\r {u}`}, the next compilation goes fine and a latex document with a TOC is generated, but I would have to do it before each compilation, wihch is not handy. Using `\r{u}` like this:

```
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={Seznam graf\r{u}}]{Graf}
```

does not help.

**Update:** This has since been resolved: http://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/22/ (as of 16.09.2015, the bug should be uploaded to CTAN on 20.09.2015 - expect some time until it trickles down to your distribution)

Comment: You can use the “long form”: `graf\r{u}`. Can you supply a minimal example? In my experiment I have no problem even with `Seznam grafů`

Comment: I do not see any `ů` in the *package* options. The package options in the question are `utf8`, `english`, and `czech`, plain ASCII strings, limited to letters and digits.

Comment: Also the `inputenc` error message is quite inconsistent with option `utf8`. The error message would be `Unicode char ... not setup for use with LaTeX`. The option of `inputenc` is different, *not* `utf8`, and the input encoding name would have been shown in the second line of the error message ```Keyboard character used is undefined\\in inputencoding `...'.```

Comment: I expanded the question and added a MWE. Using \r{u} does not help. The problem is in the toc file that gets generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `newfloat` package does a bunch of `\edef` when it should use, at least in some of those cases, `\protected@edef`.

You can solve the issue doing an indirect passage:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\protected\def\listGrafsname{Seznam grafů}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={\listGrafsname}]{Graf}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\listofGrafs
\end{document}
```

The macro `\listGrafsname` will thus pass through any `\edef` unmodified.

For `hyperref` you have to add another piece of information:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

\protected\def\listGrafsname{Seznam grafů}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={\listGrafsname}]{Graf}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\listGrafsname{Seznam grafů}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\listoffigures
\listofGrafs
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, this fixes my problem thanks! Should I report it as a bug to the creators of the newfloat package?

Comment: BTW: I also use hyperref, it now complains like this: `Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref) removing \listGrafsname' on input line 317.` but it does not seem that it changes anything. Any idea what the warning means?

Comment: @sup I added the workaround for `hyperref`

Comment: How would I input `\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={\listGrafsname}]{Graf č.}` (note the "Graf č." instead of "Graf" as in the original answer?

Comment: @sup The argument is just a string that's used to define the file extension of the auxiliary file. Use ASCII characters in it

Comment: I see, I should have RTFM first. What I want is this:`\protected\def\Grafsname{Graf č.} \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[listname={\listGrafsname},name={\Grafsname}]{Graf}`

Comment: @sup I guess this should work, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it works, sorry for not being clear:-).

Comment: I just fixed that: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/22/